# Как сделать что-бы телеграм бот отвечал на ОПРЕДЕЛЕННОЕ сообщение при ответе ему

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Хочу узнать как сделать что-бы при ответе на сообщение бота он реагировал только на определенную фразу, а не на любые ответы (для pyTelegramBotAPI). Вот мой код

```py
    @bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message is
    not None)
    def handle_text_doc(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Done')
```

Answer (score 0):

Нужно сделать проверку на определенную фразу на которую будет реагировать бот(если это reply). Если фраз несколько передайте их в список.

```
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.reply_to_message is not None)
def handle_text_doc(message):
    if message.text == 'phrase':
        bot.reply_to(message, 'Done')
```